# Is there a unique way to define an Euclidean Jordan Algebra as the product of two simple Euclidean Jordan Algebras?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, non-associative-algebras, jordan-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be two simple Euclidean Jordan Algebras. It is well known that $A\times B$ can be made into a Jordan Algebra in a unique way by defining the operation component-wise. Is it true that the product Jordan Algebra can be made Euclidean in a unique way? (the inner product on $A\times B$ is the sum of the corresponding inner products on $A$ and $B$)

Comment: To expect uniqueness, you probably want the requirement that it extends the original ones $\phi_A$ and $\phi_B$ on both $A\times\{0\}$ and $\{0\}\times B$. Otherwise you can take any positive linear combination of $\phi_A$ and $\phi_B$.

Comment: My guess is that as long you require the inner product of an atomic idempotent with itself to be normalized, that the inner product is unique. This probably follows in some way from the classification theorem for Euclidean Jordan algebras.